# Mail server in which users can only mail each other

Tags: email

I have a small community server and some users and I were chatting about email servers. We had some ideas about letting some younger users have accounts, but someone said that we would have to **block incoming and outgoing email that wasn't from or to our own users.**
Is there any way to do this?
**Users would need to have the ability to email each other.**